# windows tensorboard not work(no graph)

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.5, tensorboard

I downloaded tensorflow via pip.
here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(3.0)
b = tf.constant(5.0)
c = a * b
c_summary = tf.summary.scalar("point", c)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./board/sample_1", sess.graph)

    result = sess.run([merged])
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    writer.add_summary(result[0])
    writer.close()
```

actually, I want to test tensorboard, and source of this code is http://pythonkim.tistory.com/39.

this file is in D:\myname\python study\TensorFlow\, and I started tensorboard like this

```
  tensorboard --logdir=./board/sample_1
```

and also like this

```
tensorboard --logdir=./board
```

at D:\myname\python study\TensorFlow
and I saw this page: [watch image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5hcX.png)

windows 10, tensorflow 1.0, chrome browser

note: there is event file in ./board/sample_1.

Comment: Click on the "graphs" tab. You're on the "scalars" tab, but you didn't provide any scalar summaries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in the `" "` when starting the Tensorboard so change it to:

```
 tensorboard --logdir="./board/sample_1"
```